# How to save log files to different folders in SnowSQL multiple sessions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to start to track my SnowSQL connections, since I find I am calling the same data file, with different data multiple times a day. I see I can set a log file for my sessions in the config file under [SnowSQL Config: Configuration Options Section](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#configuration-options-section)

Is there a way to organize these log files, so I can track jobs I ran? 
Something like [Generating Unique Log files...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58348480/generating-unique-log-files-when-running-snowsql) but different file folder names. Can I create different config files for the same SnowSQL installation?

```
./snowsql -configfile nameoffileor folder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use -o log_file=~/yourlogfilename

```
snowsql -a xy12345 -u jsmith -f /tmp/input_script.sql -o log_file=~/yourlogfilename
```